# Handling launch of activities

Tags: android

i am having an application in which Mainactivity will be  launched first and checks wether the user is using the app first time or not if it is first time it launches the login page else the another page in which i have tabLayout(Homeactivity.java) with two tabs.As soon as my Homeactivity is launced it connects to the url and fetches the json data.

On click of back button on Homeactivity will exit the application.

The problem i'am facing is when i open the application its checking first time or not and opening the Homeactivity but its not connecting to the url and fetching the data unless it is remove from the recent activites.I can't understand the problem any help.following is my code in HomeActivity for back press any problem in this.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


    ImageView image=new ImageView(this);
    image.setImageResource(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setView(image)
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit the application?")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No",null)
        .show();


    }
```

and for checking the user first time or not this is the code

```
if(prefs.isLoggedIn()){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: show your code for better understanding

Comment: Please provide some code

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing the logged in check in onCreate? Do it in OnResume.
Another way to do it make a class extend Application class, in onCreate of Application class, check the first time usage. If yes, save a boolean is shared preferences.

In backpressed method, whya aren't you just doing finish?

Answer (score 0):

Please write down finish(), after startActivity() at both MainActivity and HomeActivity, then it will work.

Like

```
  startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
  finish();
```

and

```
  startActivity(intent);
  finish();
```

Comment: hi once am logging in and entering into HomeActivity fine.but when clicking on back button its exiting and if i again open app its again getting into MainActivity(Only first time this is happening) if i opening second or third time its directly entering into HomeActivity .what is the problem please let me know

Comment: Hello, See you are checking that if user has open first time app then keep the same activity, otherwise redirect to HomeActivity, So it means that till app running either in front or in background mode, whenever you will open app it will start with HomeActivity, but as soon as app stop then if you try to open it, it will first go to main activity and then redirect to home activity. So my suggestion is use splash screen where you need to check this criteria and if user first time then main activity otherwise home activity so it will show you proper flow.

Comment: but after logging first its going to MainActivity from second time it's working fine and goign to HomeActivity.i can't understand why its going to MainActivity firts time.

Comment: As I told you when app will be stop, at that time it will start from Main activity only, and if app is running in background then it will open HomeActivity. If you want to check properly this then put two different toast message on both screen and check everytime when you start app which one is called so you will get idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by using **SessionManager** class.
And check this in your **LoginActivity** weather logged in or not:

```
session = new SessionManager(getApplicationContext());

     if (session.isLoggedIn()) {
        // User is already logged in. Take him to main activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

added finish() after startactivity and also added below code

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    prefs=new PreferenceManager(getApplicationContext());
    if(prefs.isLoggedIn()){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```